# Python: openssl segmentation fault

Tags: python, openssl

I followed the instrunction on this site http://paltman.com/2007/nov/15/getting-ssl-support-in-python-251/ to install openssl.

When I go to test i get this as the output:

```
test_rude_shutdown ...
test_basic ...
Segmentation fault
```

How would I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure `which python` returns `/usr/local/bin/python`.  If not, use the Python you just built instead of your system copy!  If it does, try creating a crash dump.

Before running the tests:

`ulimit -c unlimited`

Then run the crashy test again.  Take the file which materializes in your current directory.  It's a crash dump.  Open a bug report, attach the dump, and ask the Python folks for help.